# Press enter on an image and it plays a sound?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a tabbable image that I want to play a sound if it is tabbed to and enter is pressed. It's not a button for a form or anything, just an image. How can this be done?

```
 <img src="/images/butt.gif" onclick="fartSound();" tabindex="0">
```

I already have Javascript where a sound is played when clicked, but I would really love it if I could also have the sound played when it is tabbed to and enter is pressed.

```
function fartSound(){
  var sound = new Audio('/audio/fart.mp3');
  sound.play();
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: use `el.onkey(down|up)` events. then check which key is pressed. if enter, then play your sound.

Comment: use addEventListener for focus and keydown(use if condition in the listener to filter only enter key)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the focus event with javascript.

Something like `element.addEventListener('focus', fartSound);`

### Working demo:

Just click on the white space and hit tab, you will see the console log.

```js
function fartSound(){
  console.log("Prrr");
  var sound = new Audio('/audio/fart.mp3');
  sound.play();
};


const funnyPic = document.getElementById('funnyPic');

funnyPic.addEventListener('focus', fartSound);
```

```html
 <img src="/images/butt.gif" tabindex="0" id="funnyPic">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `addEventListeners` for pressing(keydown) on 'enter'. and add `onFocus` event in HTML to call the function on click or tabbed

```js
function fartSound(){
  console.log('clicked');
  var sound = new Audio('/audio/fart.mp3');
  sound.play();
};


const element = document.getElementById('element');

element.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    //Enter key value is 13
    if(e.which == 13) {
       fartSound();
    }
});
```

```html
 <img src="/images/butt.gif" onfocus="fartSound()" tabindex="0" id="element">
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the onfocus attribute makes tabbing to the image play the sound, but the keypress part doesn't work. I followed everything. If I changed element.addEventListener to document.addEventListener, then it works globally -- duh. 

When I tab to the image with the "element" ID and press enter, nothing.

Comment: can you update your code? so that we can find what is the issue in your new code.